# Custom action send document to different page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, custom-action

I have a SharePoint 2013 provider hosted app. In the app project there is a ribbon custom action that navigates to a page in the web project. When the ribbon custom action is pressed, the selected document (the entire document not just properties) should be send to the .aspx page. On the .aspx page I want to save it in the database.
How can i send the entire document to the .aspx page?

```
<CommandUIHandler Command="Invoke_RibbonCustomAction1ButtonRequest"
                          CommandAction="~remoteAppUrl/Pages/CustomActionTarget.aspx?HostUrl={HostUrl}&amp;Source={Source}&amp;ListURLDir={ListUrlDir}&amp;SelectedListID={SelectedListId}&amp;SelectedItemID={SelectedItemId}"/>
</CommandUIHandlers>
```

This is the code I have but as you can see this will send the properties to the .aspx page and i want to send the entire document.

Answer (score 0):

Through **Source={Source}** you can get the complete url till document and when you hit it you are able to download it. so i guess you have to write code on another page from where you want to push it to DB, download it on local and from where you can push this file to sharepoint DB.
i am not able to fully answering your question but hope it may give you some directions.